# Minus sign in Axiom TR3 for Triangulated Categories

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, triangulated-categories

I have a question on the business with the minus in the axiom TR3 in
the definition of [triangulated category](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/triangulated+category#definition), namely that if $K=(K,T)$ is a triangulated category with shift functor
$T: K \to K, A \mapsto T(A):= A[1]$ then TR3 says that for any
$X, Y, Z \in K$ the sequence

$$ X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} Z \xrightarrow{h} X[1] $$

is an exact triangle if and only if

$$  Y \xrightarrow{g} Z \xrightarrow{h} X[1] \xrightarrow{-T(f)} Y[1]   $$

is exact triangle too. Note the minus sign on the right.
Originally I was curios why this sign should arrise there. The most
resonable answer I got is that the axioms of an abstract triangulated
category are 'designed' in the way that they should mimic the
triangulated structure of one of the most usual examples for triangulated
category:
The homotopy category of chain complexes $K(A)$ in an abelian category $A$
with $T$ beeing literally the shifting functor.

There the above equivalence TR3 hold. The argument exploits indeed this
minus sign as one can check eg in the proof of Lemma 2.6 in [this script](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/sosna/triangcat-lect.pdf)

Roughly the strategy of the proof is: firstly by defnition, the exact triangles
of $K(A)$ are the sequences of the form

$$   A_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{f} B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_B} C(f)_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{pr_{A[1]}} A[1]_{\bullet} ...   $$

(where $C(f):= A[1] \oplus B$ is the cone and $\iota_B, pr$ are the
canonical inclusions und projections) and all sequences
beeing isomorphic to such sequences in $K(A)$.

The proof shows that

$$   B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{h}  A[1]_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{-T f} B[1]_{\bullet} ...  $$

is isomorphic to exact triangle

$$   B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_B} C(f)_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_{C(f)}} C(\iota_B)_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{pr_{B[1]}} B[1]_{\bullet} ...   $$

and the direct calculation in the linked script exploits the minus sign. In more detail there is conctructed a homotopy-commutative diagram comparing these two sequences above.

Fine. But the proof NOT implies that without sign

$$   B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{h}  A[1]_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{T f}  B[1]_{\bullet} ...  $$

might happen to be *not* an exact triangle. The proof of the quoted lemma only assures that with the sign it is exact, that's all.

So I'm looking for an example of an exact triangle
$   A_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{f} B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_B} C(f)_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{pr_{A[1]}} A[1]_{\bullet}   $
where $  B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{h}  A[1]_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{T f}  B[1]_{\bullet}  $
is not exact triangle, ie there exist no exact triangle
$   A'_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{f'} B'_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_B'} C(f)_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{pr_{A'[1]}} A'[1]_{\bullet}   $
isomorphic to it.

A 'weaker' version of my question might be formulated as that I'm looking
for an exact triangle as above where
$ B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{g} C_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{h}  A[1]_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{T f}  B[1]_{\bullet}$
is not isomorphic to $   B_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_B} C(f)_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{\iota_{C(f)}} C(\iota_B)_{\bullet}  \xrightarrow{pr_{B[1]}} B[1]_{\bullet}   $. Is there a nice example known?

Comment: See Remark 3.2 in the text you link. It is not true without $-$.

Comment: @markvs: You mean the remark 3.2 from nlab? Or possibly you mean Rmk 3.4? But is there any concrete example where this fails?

Comment: Your link http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/triangulated+category#definition remark 3.2. An example should be easy. But I do not care about this enough to think about an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathsf{Ab}$ be the category of abelian groups, and in $K(\mathsf{Ab})$ let $A=B=\mathbb{Z}$, considered as a complex concentrated in degree zero, and let $f:A\to B$ be multiplication by $3$.

If $B\to C(f)\to A[1]\xrightarrow{Tf}B[1]$ were an exact triangle as well as $B\to C(f)\to A[1]\xrightarrow{-Tf}B[1]$, then by axiom TR4 we would get a map of triangles
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
B@>>>C(f)@>>>A[1]@>{Tf}>>B[1]\\
@|@|@VVgV@|\\
B@>>>C(f)@>>>A[1]@>{-Tf}>>B[1]\\
\end{CD}
But it is easy to check that there is no map $g$ that makes this diagram commute, since the right hand square only commutes if $g=-\text{id}_{A[1]}$, but for the middle square to commute, $g$ has to be multiplication by some integer $n\equiv1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: you mean these conditions have to be fulfilled in order that the right and middle squares *homotopy* commute, right?

Comment: Then indeed as far as I understand your argument correctly, the 'naive' commutativity of the right square is the same as homotopy commutativity, since $A[1]$ and $B[1]$ are concentrated only in degree $1$ and therefore any homotopy map $A_n \to B_{n+1}$ is zero.

Comment: For the middle square, there could exist a homotopy $s^k: C(f)_k \to A[1]_{k+1}$ but by definition of $C(f)$ the only non zero $s^k$ would be for $k=0$ which would also be given by multiplication with an integer $l$, since $C(f)_0=B_0= \mathbb{Z} = A[0]_1$. Finally, the homotopy commutativity condition in the middle square would become only interesting in degree $1$, where the conditions reads as $1-g= d_0 \circ s^1 +s^0 \circ d_1= s^0 \circ d_1= s^0 \cdot 3 = l \cdot 3$, ie a multiplication by $ l \cdot 3$. That's exactly the condition from your answer, thank you.

Comment: @KarlPeter Yes, by “commute” I mean “commute as a diagram over the category $K(\mathsf{Ab})$”.